# Is it normal for a 14GB VHD file to be converted to a 100GB+ BIN file?

Tags: virtualbox, qemu, vdi

i want to convert a vhd-file to vdi and found a manual which says i have to convert the vhd first to bin. But qemu-img creates a 130GB file (even if theres not enough space on disk) from the 14GB vhd-file. Is this a common behavior ?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 0):

If the size (or maximum-size) of the partition in the VHD is 130GB, then yes, it's normal. VHD/VDI support "sparse" disk files, i.e. they only take up the actual amount of space used, not the specified size. BIN has no such support, so the VHD will be expanded out to the full size, although it will mostly be zeros.